# Does an Egyptian student resident in the EU need a visa for a short stay in Switzerland?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, switzerland, egyptian-citizens

I am an Egyptian student and willing to visit Switzerland for less than 90 days. I hold a Portuguese residence permit (due to being a student, which I renew every year). I usually have no problems traveling to Schengen area countries. My question is, if I intend to visit Switzerland for less than 90 days, would I need any kind of authorization?

Comment: Switzerland is part of the Schengen area.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro indeed it is.  It's probably worth noting that this is in spite of the fact that it is neither part of the EU nor of the EEA, which is perhaps the reason why some might want extra reassurance.

Answer (score 6):

You can travel to Switzerland visa-free since you hold a Portuguese residence permit:

> Third-state citizens who hold a valid and recognised travel document
>   are exempt from the visa obligation for stays not exceeding 90 days in
>   any 180-day period (see Annex 2 to the to the Visa Handbook I and the
>   SEM Supplement) if they also hold:
>
> - a valid residence permit (list of residence permits issued by Schengen states) or
> - a national visa of a Schengen state (D visa).

[source](https://www.sem.admin.ch/content/dam/data/sem/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/bfm/bfm-anh01-liste2-e.pdf)

To be completely sure, please refer to the list of residence permits to check for your specific residence permit (see the link in p. 3.2 of the document linked above).